# Why was my career related question considered off-topic?

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question, on-topic-definition, career

Here is the link to the question that was considered off-topic: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/277933/69485

I read the answer to another question on here (meta.programmers.stackexchange.com) that as long as the question doesn't just apply to me and it applies to programmers in general, then the career question should be acceptable. Why was my question not considered on-topic specifically? What can I do (if anything) to change the question?

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest reading [Why was my question closed as off topic?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6488/) which seeks to get the current understanding of career questions.  The scope of the site has changed over time and things that were acceptable a few years ago aren't acceptable now. The [help center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has been updated to show this and provides a link to this material. For freelancing work, you may wish to look at [freelancing.se](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/search?q=where+to+find+work) ...

Comment: ... though be sure to read the scope of the site, what is on and off topic there become somewhat familiar with the site's scope and expectations before jumping in and posting a question.